# ¿Cómo mando informacion de ASHX a HTML?

Tags: c#, html

Tengo una página HTML en la cual mando a llamar un Handler de ASHX, pero quiero que lo que trae el Handler de la Base de Datos se despliegue en el HTML dentro de una etiqueta `<h3>`

Tengo este código:

```
public class Titulo : IHttpHandler
{
    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //write your handler implementation here.
        ;

        string Order = context.Request.QueryString["Order"];

        string IdOrder = "0";

        switch (Order)
        {
            /*Pagina Index Portada Perfil -------*/
            case "1":
                { IdOrder = "1"; Title(context, IdOrder); }
                break;
            case "2":
                { IdOrder = "2"; Title(context, IdOrder); }
                break;
            case "3":
                { IdOrder = "3"; Title(context, IdOrder); }
                break;
            case "4":
                { IdOrder = "4"; Title(context, IdOrder); }
                break;
            case "5":
                { IdOrder = "5"; Title(context, IdOrder); }
                break;
        }
    }
    public void Title(HttpContext context, string Id)
    {
        /* Hace la conexion */

        bool flag = false;

        string Identificador = Id;

        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Aviso"].ToString()))
        {
            /* abre la connexion */

            conexion.Open();
            /*Ejecuta el stored procedure */
            using (SqlCommand orden = new SqlCommand("EXEC dbo.PROC_AVISO_Avisos " + Identificador.ToString(), conexion))
            {
                flag = true;
                using (SqlDataReader lector = orden.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (lector.Read())
                    {
                        string Titulo = lector[0].ToString(); //Titulo
                        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                        context.Response.Write(Titulo);
                    }
                    lector.Close();
                }
            }
            conexion.Close();
        }
    }
```

En la parte de `lector[0].ToString();` si me trae la información, pero no sé la forma en la que pueda poner esa información dentro del HTML

Answer (score 1):

Si usas jQuery es muy sencillo llamar al handler ashx y volcar el contenido devuelto en un elemento HTML.

```js
        $(function() {
            $('.title').load('/Titulo.ashx');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="title"></span>
```

Este ejemplo llama al handler Titulo.ashx y muestra su contenido en el span decorado con la clase "title".

Por supuesto deberás reemplazar la url "/Titulo.ashx" por la ruta de tu handler.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que estas usando un Handler asumo que el resultado se debe hacer tras una acción o evento de tu pagina y de manera asíncrona.

para esto puedes usa la libreria [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) y usar [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) en donde pasas la url del archivo .ashx y la respuesta se retorna en un CallBack, adicionalmente si quieres enviar datos desde el HTML usas la propiedad `Data` asi:

```
$.ajax({
         url: 'Handlers/titulo.ashx',
         data: { identificador:'valor'//parametros opcionales
         dataType: 'text', 
         type: 'POST',
         error: function () {console.log('sucedio un error'); },
        //en este punto usas tu resultado del backend 
         success: function (respuestaTitulo) {<h2>respuestaTitulo</h2>}
});
```

esta fracción de codigo puede ir por ejemplo en el evento click de un botón.

espero te sirva.

Comment: me puedes ayudar quiero capturar valores de ashx pero copie tu codigo sale un error

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar variables de sesión, se trabajan desde el Code Behind, y pueden ser de cualquier tipo, ya sea un dato primitivo o una clase (hecha por ti o de las que trae ya C#)

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como instanciar una variable de sesión:

```
Session["nombreVarSession"] = new DataTable(); //un DataTable por ejemplo
```

Después para recuperarlo al otro lado simplemente accedes a la variable de sesión y le haces un casteo.

```
DataTable nombreVariable = (DataTable)Session["nombreVarSession"];
```